# C# - How to assign a property value to a object without explicitly calling the property name

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have an application where I have a class  with 100 property values

For example.

```
Class RequestData{
 String PropertName1 {get;set;}
 String PropertName2 {get;set;}
 String PropertName3 {get;set;}
 .
 .
 .
 String PropertName100 {get;set;}
}
```

I have a List> and this has all the propertyname and propertyvalues. So, ideally this has

```
PropertName1 = "Timothy"
PropertName2 = "rajan"
.
.
.
PropertName100 = "alex"
```

I need to create an instance of RequestData and assign all the property values to each of the property names

In this scenario, I need to do like this which will result in 100s of lines

```
 RequestData requestData = new RequestData ();
 requestData.PropertName1 = "Timothy" ;
 requestData.PropertName2 = "Rajan" ;
 requestData.PropertName3 = "Alex" ;
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I can loop into the List but not sure how to smartly do it something like

```
 RequestData requestData = new RequestData ();
 requestData.[key]= value ;
```

I hope I made it clear. Any help would be great.

Comment: If you're just making a request object, why not use an `ExpandoObject` - you can treat it like a dictionary or an object.

Comment: You have not shown a list, you've shown what looks like multiple assignments. Can you please show an actual sample of the "list of property name and values"? Is it something like `var propNamesAndValues = new List<string> { "PropertName1 = Timothy", "PropertName2 = rajan", ... , "PropertName100 = alex" };`

Comment: Another idea, if you can get that input in JSON format, then you could use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) and deserialize it into your `RequestData` object.

Comment: As pointed out by @gilliduck, without more context of what you're trying to achieve, the question isn't really answerable. For example, what is that "RequestData" you're talking about? If the name of the properties match, maybe you could use AutoMapper or some other library.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with reflection

```
_list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
   {
      new Tuple<string, string>("PropertName1", "asd"),
      new Tuple<string, string>("PropertName2", "sdfgds"),
      new Tuple<string, string>("PropertName3", "dfgdfg"),
      new Tuple<string, string>("PropertName100", "dfgdfg")
   };


var requestData = new RequestData();

foreach (var tuple in _list)
{
   requestData.GetType()
              .GetProperty(tuple.Item1, BindingFlags.Public| BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance )
             ?.SetValue(requestData, tuple.Item2);

}
```

Or an extension method

```
public void UpdateProperties<T>(this T obj, List<Tuple<string, string>> list) where T : class
{
   foreach (var tuple in _list)
   {
      var type = obj.GetType();
         var property = type.GetProperty(tuple.Item1, BindingFlags.Public| BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance );
      if(property == null)
         continue;
      property.SetValue(obj, tuple.Item2);
   }
}
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0YXXfM)

**Additional Resources**

[Type.GetProperty Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Searches for the public property with the specified name.

[PropertyInfo.SetValue Method (Object, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Sets the property value of a specified object.

[BindingFlags Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Specifies flags that control binding and the way in which the search
>   for members and types is conducted by reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Without more specifics though it's very difficult to give a "good" response. Based on what you've shown (and making a probably bad assumption on my part) here is one of several different possible ways to do so. I don't really recommend this personally, but perhaps it (with other answers/comments) will start you down the path that you actually want/need to go.

I should mention that there are more efficient methods for this, but wanted to show a rudimentary method that may be a bit more apparent as to what is actually happening.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var propertyList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PropertyName1","Value1"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PropertyName2","Value2"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PropertyName3","Value3"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PropertyName4","Value4"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PropertyName5","Value5"),
        };

        var requestData = new RequestData();
        //reflection allows you to loop through the properties of a class
        foreach (var property in requestData.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            //you can loop through your list (here I made an assumption that it's a list of KeyValuePair)
            foreach (var keyValuePair in propertyList)
            {
                //if the key matches the property name, assign the value
                if (property.Name.Equals(keyValuePair.Key))
                {
                    property.SetValue(requestData, keyValuePair.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        //to show that they are properly set
        Console.WriteLine(requestData.PropertyName1);
        Console.WriteLine(requestData.PropertyName2);
        Console.WriteLine(requestData.PropertyName3);
        Console.WriteLine(requestData.PropertyName4);
    }
}

public class RequestData
{
    public string PropertyName1 { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName2 { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName3 { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName4 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing another similar answer into the ring, this one using a list of strings and splitting them on the `=` sign, then using reflection to try to get the property name, and if that's not null, set the property value of our object:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var propNamesAndValues = new List<string>
    {
        "PropertName1 = Timothy",
        "PropertName2 = Rajan",
        "PropertName100 = Alex",
    };

    var requestData = new RequestData();

    foreach (var propNameValue in propNamesAndValues)
    {
        var parts = propNameValue.Split('=');
        if (parts.Length < 2) continue;

        var propName = parts[0].Trim();
        var propValue = parts[1].Trim();

        typeof(RequestData).GetProperty(propName)?.SetValue(requestData, propValue);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", requestData.PropertName1,
        requestData.PropertName2, requestData.PropertName100);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]